# ASP.NET Radio buttons selection to hide/show div section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

I am trying to hide a  section based on the result of a Yes/No radio button selection where yes is true and no is false. I have it to where if the user selects a button, the field is shown, but it does it for both yes or no, also if the user clicks the no, it should remain hidden(which it doesn't). Thanks for any help.

Here is the JQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
        if ($(this).prop('#ImportPartRadio', true)) {
            $('#ImportPartQuestions').show();
        }

       else if ($(this).prop('#ImportPartRadio', false)){
           $('#ImportPartQuestions').hide();
       }
   });
});
```

Here is the div sections

```
@*import parts radio button*@
    <div class="span-18 last" id="ImportPart">
        <table class="item-display">
            <tr>
                <td class="label required" id="ImportPartRadio">
                <div class='tooltip'>Is this an import part?<span class="tooltiptext">This information can be used to calssify the part for US Customs purposes.</span></div></td>
                <td class="value" colspan="5">
                    Yes: @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ImportPart, true) 
                    No: @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ImportPart, false) 
                </td>
            </tr>
             </table>
    </div>


    @*This table is for full procurement and sales procurement setup only*@
    <div class="span-18 last" id="ImportPartQuestions">
        <table class="item-display">
            <tr>
                <td class="label">If an import, what is the material and function of part?</td>
                <td colspan="5" class="value">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.MaterialAndFunction, new { @placeholder = "Description Here", maxLength = 300 })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MaterialAndFunction)
                </td>
            </tr>
     </table>
</div>
```

I have been googling for hours and can't seem to find a solution the works, this is as close as any of them come to fully working.

[Here is the html code rendered by the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkQ7d.png)

Comment: Is `#ImportPart` your intended `property` ?

Comment: #ImportPart is the the div id, I meant for it to be #ImportPartRadio, i edited it. Thank you, results are still the same as described.

Comment: Read about `jQuery .prop`..I guess you have misunderstood it..

Comment: Ok, then my question is, how do I go about doing what I wish to do, I am able using a drop down but I can't seem to have a clue when using a yes or know radio button.

Comment: Can you share parsed/browser-rendered HTML ?

Comment: @Rayon I added a picture hopefully that is a screenshot of what i think you wanted to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="ImportPart"]').change(function() {
    var radioValue = $(this).val();
    var questionsDiv = $('#ImportPartQuestions');
    if (radioValue == "True") {
      questionsDiv.show();
    } else {
      questionsDiv.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

**OR using `.toggle( display )`**

```js
$('input[name="ImportPart"]').change(function() {
  $('#ImportPartQuestions').toggle(this.value === "True");
});
```

Comment: This works exactly how I wanted it to! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ImportPartRadio input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === 'True') {
            $('#ImportPartQuestions').show();
        } else {
           $('#ImportPartQuestions').hide();
       }
   });
});
```

// edited to match case with your True value, and fixed a typo.

Comment: when i try this solution, the div section stays hidden no matter what. But thank you for trying.

Answer (score 0):

Why not get the change event which will be more robust:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val()==true) {
            $('#ImportPartQuestions').show();
        }

       else {
           $('#ImportPartQuestions').hide();
       }
   });
});
```